# Evitar que se modifique un atributo lista de un objeto al modificar el atributo lista de otro objeto de la misma clase

Tags: python, lista, objeto, clase, referencias

Tengo el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, lista = []):
        self.lista = lista
        
    def append(self, elemento):
        self.lista.append(elemento)
          
a = Clase()
b = Clase()
a.append('elemento')

print(a.lista) #['elemento']
print(b.lista) #['elemento']
```

¿Cómo puedo evitar que al modificar el atributo `lista` de `a` se modifique el atributo `lista` de `b`? ¿Y por qué sucede exactamente?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: aunque no lo creas es por la referencia del parámetro por defecto. Quita `lista=[]` y en la inicialización del atributo haces `self.lista = []` y problema resuelto :D

Comment: @Christian. La función debe poder recibir una lista como argumento. Si la quitas, ya no es la misma función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error común: la expresión `lista = []` en la declaración de la función se calcula sólo una vez, al cargar el módulo.

Mira este ejemplo, con una función `fcn` que retorna su argumento multiplicado por dos:

```
a = 1

def fcn(param = a):
    return param * 2

print(fcn())  => 2
a = 2
print(fcn())  => 2
```

En ambos casos la respuesta es 2. ¿Por qué? Pues porque el valor de `a` se calculó en la carga del código, y luego se reutilizó, sin importar que `a` haya cambiado de valor entre llamadas.

#### El caso con listas (y otros contenedores)

Cuando dices `lista = []` estas creando una lista que luego utilizaras (si es necesario) en las subsiguientes llamadas a la función. Es la misma lista, no se reinicializa en cada llamada, por lo que todas las operaciones son permanentes.

La solución es cambiar la declaración, asignando `None` a la lista y luego inicializandola dentro del código:

```
def __init__(self, lista = None):

    if lista is None:
        lista = []

    self.lista = lista
```

El resultado es que cada vez que ejecutas el método sin pasar `lista`, Python le asigna el valor por default definido (`None`).

Cuando el código ve un `None`, crea una nueva lista exclusivamente para el uso dentro de la función (o de la instancia, en este caso).

La comparación tiene que ser contra `None`; esto no funciona:

```
if not lista:
    lista = []
```

pues una lista vacia y `None` ambos dan `False`. Entonces, hay que explicitar:

```
if lista is None:
    lista = []
```

#### Moraleja

Si vas a usar valores por default en una función, asegurate de que el valor sea *inmutable*, un `int`, `float`, `str`, `None` o similar.

Para cualquier valor *mutable*, asignale `None` en la declaración y luego inicializalo dentro del código de la función.

Mutables son las listas, diccionarios, conjuntos y cualquier contenedor que permite alterar su contenido.

#### Demo

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, lista=None):
        if lista is None:
            lista = []
        self.lista = lista


    def append(self, elemento):
        self.lista.append(elemento)


a = Clase()
b = Clase()
a.append('elemento')

print(a.lista)  # ['elemento']
print(b.lista)  # ['elemento']
```

produce:

```
['elemento']
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma que lo he resuelto es la siguiente:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self, lista = []):
        items = []
        for i in lista:
            items.append(i)
        self.lista = items
        
    def append(self, elemento):
        self.lista.append(elemento)
```

Puede que no sea la forma mas optima, pero es funcional.

Comment: pues sip, pero no explicas el porque sucede :(